# Parallel Data Loading in Greenplum

Tags: database, database-design, greenplum

Greenplum says that it has parallel data loading. I have a doubt regarding how it works. Please do explain it to me. I understand that records are read in parallel but I can't understand how parallel writes are done. Is the parallel writes done on the same database or is it done on different databases(segments)? Please do explain. Thanks

Comment: -1: this is explained in Admin guide, chapter 12 "Loading and Unloading Data"

Answer (score 1):

The parallel writes are done on different segments, with data being fed by 1 or more instances of gpfdist running on the ETL server(s). I suspect a significant part of the magic is the `distributed by` extension that is used to scatter the rows of a database across the segment servers.

Answer (score 0):

Concurrent reads/writes can be done at segment level with the help of gpfdist or gphdfs.

For example, if you want to unload data to a file on disk, you can use a writable external table which connects to several gpfdist locations, and each data segment would write data to those destinations is parallel.

Answer (score 0):

John is correct.

Each instance of gpfdist, by default, will handle 4 concurrent connections.
When loading, each segment with a connection will read their "chunk" of data and process according the distribution hash of the table.

See: https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/parallel_etl_with_greenplum/